# Push notification service for iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, netmera

I have developed an iOS app and have my server (just a couple of php files and a database) set up on GoDaddy.com.

Unfortunately GoDaddy.com does not allow me to send a push notification from its server because it requires to use a specific port.

I have users' device token stored in my database, is there any service online that I can use to send push notification with the device token I have?

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17779756/983912

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netmera (www.netmera.com), which provides a RESTful API and a lot of free push alert and rich html push.

This tutorial page (http://cp.netmera.com/nm/admin/tutorial).

Answer (score 4):

There are some very good industrial solutions for iOS push notifications service that use APNS:

- [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi) - free for 1M notifications per month, and unlimited notifications for 19.99 per month, and you can import your users via the API or b sending the a csv file - [here is the documentation](http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/PushApps+Home)
- [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) - free up to 1M notifications per month, afterwards you are charged per 1000 notifications
- [Parse](https://parse.com/) - also free for the first 1M notifications
- [PushWoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) - free for 1M devices, premium plans are from 39 EURO

**Diclaimer** - I work in [PushApps](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) and also use their product in my applications for over a year now.

Comment: Also we can choose https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device